# how to return a db_query as an option list and display it

Tags: webforms, database

```
<?php

/**
 * Define callbacks that can be used as custom select list options.
 */
function webform_contacts_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();

  if (function_exists('webform_options_contacts')) {
    $items['contacts'] = array(
      'title' => t('Contact List'),
      'options callback' => 'webform_options_contacts',
    );
  }

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Option list containing Contacts.
 * Pull a list of users where status=active and rid=5 from database.
 */
function webform_options_contacts() {
  $items = array();

  $query = db_query("SELECT realname.realname AS realname_realname, realname.uid AS realname_uid, users.uid AS uid, 'user' AS field_data_field_gal_phone_user_entity_type FROM {users} users INNER JOIN {users_roles} users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid LEFT JOIN {realname} realname ON users.uid = realname.uid WHERE (( (users.status <> '0') AND (users_roles.rid = '5') )) ORDER BY realname_realname ASC");

  $results = $query->execute();
}
```

I created a custom module for displaying an extra option list. The example provided by *Drupal 7 Webform Cookbook* I used worked; using a hard coded list and it displays fine.

I want to use a db_query to populate the list. I have this code (shown above) but am unable to see anything displayed. Help! I am sure I am missing the command to properly get this to display as a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`DatabaseStatementInterface::fetchAllKeyed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchAllKeyed/7), but as you only need 2 columns it would be wise to change your query slightly. Essentially you want to select just one for the identifier, and one for the label. Something like this:

```
$sql = ' 
    SELECT realname.uid, realname.realname 
    FROM {users} users 
    INNER JOIN {users_roles} users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid 
    LEFT JOIN {realname} realname ON users.uid = realname.uid 
    WHERE users.status <> :status AND users_roles.rid = :rid
    ORDER BY realname.realname';

$args = array(':status' => 0, ':rid' => 5);

return db_query($sql, $args)->fetchAllKeyed();
```

That will return an array with the 1st column (uid) as keys and the 2nd column (realname) as values, which you can use verbatim as options for a form element.

You don't *have* to return just 2 columns from the query, as `fetchAllKeyed()` allows you to specify the index for both key and value; but as you're not using the data for anything else, it makes sense to avoid the overhead of the extra columns.

Slightly unrelated: you shouldn't call `exceute()` on the return from `db_query()`, as the query has already been executed by that point. You can either use one of the helper methods like `fetchAllKeyed()`, or iterate directly over the values, e.g.

```
foreach (db_query($sql) as $row) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks Clive. fetchAllKeyed(); is a more complete solution instead of my trying to create an array manually. Thank you for the example you provided.

Comment: "This method is only useful for two-column result sets." and I need to return a third column with records from another table also. I am combining the third table for the phone number to be displayed. The phone number is saved in `field_data_field_contact_phone.field_contact_phone_value` the connecting column is `user.uid = field_data_field_contact_phone.entity_id`

Comment: maybe I should just be using fetchAll(); or fetchAllAssoc();